# IIS auto redirect from http to https doesn't work in some cases

Tags: http, redirect, iis, https

I am trying to config my website so if user accesses the page in insecure mode, he will be automatically redirected to https.

By using rewrite module: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/

bellow is my code snippet

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="http://(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works in some cases.

[image: When the request is http then redirect to https]

But some cases, it doesn't work

[image: When the request is http --> ok]

Both of two cases I tested on client (Chrome for both). On my server, Firefox --> ok, IE --> not ok.

I have no idea to solve this, can someone give some.

Thank you.

Update. I have tried many solutions like Victor Leontyev's answer but they didn't work.

[image]

The result was

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot. It's working only for you because the redirect is cached on your PC. 
[image]
Your rule is not correct. The correct rule should be like that:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried many similar solutions like your but they didn't work. Please check my update above.

Comment: Did u try my solution? And how did you enable https? Which of these options? https://imgur.com/a/d1xtI Sometime it matters, because in option 1 IIS still doesn't know that SSL is enabled

Comment: Hello, Yes. I have tried your solution, I believe it works in other cases but not mine. You can see my screenshot in the question. (I updated my question after tried your solution). And I can make sure SSL is enabled successfully on my server because when I enter the url with https://, the web page works and the browser notice the connection is secure.

Comment: Are you using proxies like Cloudflare? And how did you enable https? Did you do that on IIS level?